# Renaming multiple subdirectories with the name of parent directory as prefix

Tags: python, bash, shell, file-rename, prefix-operator

I have multiple directories 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444 and inside each directory is subdirectory named as for example _apple. I want to add the parent folder name as prefix to the sub directory.

What I have is

```
1111
 _apple

2222
 _apple

3333
 _apple
```

what I want is

```
1111
 1111_apple

2222
 2222_apple

3333
 3333_apple
```

Please if anyone can help ?

I tried this but it works for only 1st file and does not iterate. I have more than 100 directories and it works only for 1st one.

```
for folder in */; do 
    
    for sample_num in */; do
        cd $sample_num
        sample="${sample_num::-1}"
        for rename in _apple; do
            mv -- "$rename" "{$sample}_{$rename}"
        done
        cd ..
        cd ..
    done
```

Comment: You're missing a `done` in the code.

Comment: Are there also files in the `1111`, `2222`, etc. directories that should not be renamed?

Comment: Is there a missing `cd "$folder"`? If not, `folder` and `sample_num` are looping over the same folders.

Comment: `${sample_num::-1}` means `sample_num` without the last character. Is this really what you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the `cd` commands. Use a wildcard in both the directory and subdirectory portion. Then split it with parameter expansion operators to get the parent and child names.

```
for subdir in */*; do
    if [ -d "$subdir" ]
    then
        dirname=${subdir%/*}
        subdirname=${subdir#*/}
        mv "$subdir" "$dirname/$dirname$subdirname"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Also, The answer to your previous questions, Yes there are other files in each parent directory (i.e., 1111, 2222, 333) too, but they are different files not directories. Many thanks! Finally I can proceed :)

Comment: That's what `if [ -d` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Saw you added the python tag to your question. Here is a workaround for python

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = "The/directory/where/1111,2222,3333/are/located"
for i in Path(root).iterdir():
    for j in i.glob("*_apple"):
        j.rename(i / f"{i.name}{j.name}")
```